# Switching DVI socket

Tags: 10.10, xorg, nvidia, dualhead

I have Ubuntu 10.10 x86_64 with Nvidia 9800 gt and Nvidia driver version 270.41.06

My video card has two DVI sockets, but I only use the single monitor configuration. Now, I think the main DVI socket might be busted, so I want to try to enable the other as the main one, however, I don't know how to achieve that. I tried just plugging the monitor in that socket but it won't auto-detect it (it would have been way too easy to just work).

This is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: builtin, VertRefresh source: builtin
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC"
    HorizSync       31.5 - 84.7
    VertRefresh     60.0 - 78.0
    ModeLine       "1080p" 172.8 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GT"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "1024x768 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "CustomEDID" "CRT-0:/home/charlesq/lg.bin"
    Option         "TVStandard" "HD1080p"
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1080p +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have some way of controlling the computer now? Can you `SSH` in? Last resort: Pull the disk out, stick it in another computer and that will let you edit files.

Assuming you can get access to things, edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as root (eg `sudoedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` if you're `ssh`ed into or are on your computer).

You want to look at the screen section. There should be a `Option "metamodes"` line in there that might look something like:

```
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1200"
```

Change `DFP-0` to `DFP-1` (or `DFP-2` or `DFP-3` if your card also has HDMI sockets). Save the file and boot up (or just run `sudo restart gdm` if you're on the machine over SSH)

Comment: yes i can definitely ssh to it

Comment: so, i will try to add DFP-0: to the metamodes options, but notice that i rely on the CustomEDID option to get right fullhd resolution, do i have to replace the CRT-0 to CRT-1 options too, as well the TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder?

Comment: it is sort of working, but i'm seeing the exact same issue that made me thought that the socket was busted; the image comes and goes inexplicably, just like if the cable was broken. I tested this cable and the vga/dvi converters with my laptop and they work fine, so it seems it might be the video card that is dying..... (sobs)